# Clickable ToolStripMenuItem Image

Tags: c#, winforms, click, contextmenu, toolstripitem

I'm working on a C# winForm app that has a ContextMenuStrip that adds toolStripMenuItems dynamically. I also have an icon in my resource file that I assign to the toolStripMenuItem.Image property and I handle the toolStripMenuItem.Click event. I actually want to handle the click event if the Image (icon) is clicked but Icon/Image does not have a click event. How do create a click icon that can assigned to the image property of the toolStripMenuItem?

Thanks in advance

-DA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to customize the ToolStripItem and obtain the rectangle in which the image lies using the **ContentRectangle** property.

Have a look at the [ComputeImageAndTextLayout code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.contentrectangle.aspx) on MSDN which calculates the rectangle in which the image lies.

In the MouseDown event of the ToolStripItem you will obtain the coordinates of the mouse in the ToolStripItem when the MouseDown event occurred as shown below

```
void item_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x = e.X;
    int y = e.Y;
}
```

You will then have to calculates if your MouseDown coordinates lies in the rectangle obtained and raise a ImageClicked event.

Using the same approach you could also raise a TextClicked event.

Comment: yeah, i'm reading it now! i having a little trouble computing the image rectange but thats what i want! Thanks again!

Comment: hey Romulus I got it THX!!!!! and i got before my manager got here lol! thanks i'm really grateful, you've saved me 2x!